# Check if user comes from a certain url

Tags: php, if-statement, url, redirect

I am offering my users a key in order to access my program.
I have a key page like this https://example.com/key

My program redirects them to a common link shortener with ads, after they've skipped through the ads they will be redirected to the key page (https://example.com/key)

However my users can avoid this step by simply going to https://example.com/key directy instead of using the link shortener.

I've tried this in php already:

```
 $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

 if (strpos($referer, 'www.linkshortenerexample.com') === FALSE)
 { 
    header('Location: https://example.com/key'); 
    exit();
 }
```

This hasn't worked due to the fact that it doesn't support https redirects.
Also HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed quite easily therefore I'd need something better either way.

I was also thinking about a timer which starts on the first page, then redirects to the linkshortener and after the linkshortener has been completed it redirects to the second page where it gets the timer from the first page and checks if the user has spent a certain amount of time on this page and if not it won't redirect them to the key page. Sadly I have no idea where to start there and if it'd even work.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: whats key used for can it be used to know what site/link its from? else maybe include a *use once* token in the url as a param, else making them login is the only way to prevent multi-use and fakery

Comment: No you can't track it back as far as I know, the key contains the remote ip address of the client and hashes it in sha256. The key simple gets pasted into my program which checks if it's correct or not. I think a use once token can be easily bypassed as well. I just want them to use the link shortener instead of going to my url directly because otherwise it would be a big loss for my business.

Other than that, thank you for your quick response.

Comment: You should track it by session - if possible

Comment: Do you control the link shortener? Any functionality to verify that they've gone through the link shortener, which doesn't rely on the referrer, will have to have have functionality added to the shortener itself. You can probably hack around this by adding one-time use urls to the shortener - add a new shortened link for `/key?short_key=<one_time_use_key>` and redirect to the created shortened link. When the `short_key` is seen again, mark it as used and don't accept it a second time. If / when used the second time, repeat the short link creation and redirect he user to the shortner.